How to dynamically change the background of fonts in Unity
Currently, the burgundy part of the font shadow uses outline and underlay. I don’t know how to complete the rose red part of the background. If you add a sibling image component, you need to crop the image. But I want to achieve the effect of dynamic loading, which means that when I change the text, the background shape can also change to match the text without setting an additional image.
enter image description here
Hope your help .I have tried many ways，but  I still don't know how to do.

You can't create this text with single material and text with native unity.
You can create another text and send it to back of first text. Also create a material with rose red and adjust material settings like facing etc.
If you're changing texts in script you should change both of them with this way.
Or look for text packages in asset store.

So,there is no script that can be dynamically controlled.I got it,thank you very much
